# Subquerying with a limit

Tags: mysql, subquery, limit

I have a site with categories and topics. Some categories are parents/children of each other (only one nested level). I'm trying to select the most recent topic from each family of categories (i.e. at most one topic from either a parent or child). Here's what I'm trying now:

```
SELECT topics.id
FROM topics, categories
WHERE topics.category_id = categories.id
AND ( categories.id IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
      OR categories.parent IN ( 1, 2, 3 ))
ORDER BY topics.posted DESC
```

If I run this query as it is, it retrieves every single topic. If I add `LIMIT 1` at the end, it only retrieves 1 total (not 1 per family). If I add `LIMIT 3` at the end, it'll retrieve the 3 most recent from all categories. I want **one** topic from each category. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit rough, but should do what you want:

```
SELECT topics.id FROM
  (SELECT MAX(topics.posted) AS date, categories.id AS id
  FROM topics, categories
  WHERE topics.category_id = categories.id
  AND ( categories.id IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
      OR categories.parent IN ( 1, 2, 3 ))
  GROUP BY categories.id) t1
JOIN topics 
ON topics.posted = t1.date AND topics.category_id = ti.id
```

Comment: Hmm, actually, if the latest topic within a family belongs to a parent instead of a child, it will only pull a topic from a child - I think this is because we're grouping by `categories.id`. Any thoughts on how to fix this? Thanks again

Comment: @andrewtweber without knowing more about the structure it is difficult to know  . . . perhaps changing to `GROUP BY categories.id, categories.parent` - this will select an id for each distinct id-parent combination.

Comment: That didn't work but it's fine. This retrieves the latest topic for each parent and each child, so I can then just use PHP to compare the parent/child dates to find which one is actually the latest. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for GROUP BY:

```
SELECT topics.id,MAX(topics.posted) AS postDate
FROM topics, categories
WHERE topics.category_id = categories.id
AND ( categories.id IN ( 1, 2, 3 )      
OR categories.parent IN ( 1, 2, 3 ))
GROUP BY topics.category_id
ORDER BY topics.posted DESC
```

Comment: This is a step closer, thank you; it's now retrieving one topic per family. However it's not getting the most recent one.

Comment: It will retrieve random `topics.id` in each group.

Comment: Sorry missed that part.  You can change it to SELECT topics.id,MAX(topics.posted) AS postDate FROM...